# How to Fix Convex-Concave Sign in tkz-tab with Point d'inflexion Inside Triangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-tab

I'm currently working with tkz-tab to create a table of convex-concave signs for a mathematical function. I've successfully generated the table, but I'm facing an issue with the positioning of the point d'inflexion (A(a,f(a))) inside the triangle.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools, mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \square
%\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
    
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[double distance=0.04cm]
    \tkzTabInit[color,espcl=2.5, lgt=2.3]{$x$ /1, $f^{''}(x)$/1, Convexité\\ de $\left(\mathcal{C}_f\right)$ /2}%
    {$- \infty$,, $a$,, $+\infty$}%
    \tkzTabLine{ , , - , , z ,  , + }
    \tkzTabLine{,\text{Concave},,,\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{\text{Point}}{\text{d'inflexion}}{$A(a,f(a))$},,,\text{Convexe},}
    \draw (N32) to (M23);
    \draw (N32) to (M33);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The issue is that the point d'inflexion (A(a,f(a))) is not correctly positioned inside the triangle formed by the concave and convex signs. I've tried adjusting the coordinates manually, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Any suggestions on how to properly position the point d'inflexion inside the triangle would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Is this representation a standard one?

Comment: I'm not sure, but most Francophones use this representation, along with some figures, to design concave and convex shapes

Comment: Is the notation style used in the partly wrong table on page 66 of the `tkz-tab` documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
    
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[double distance=0.04cm]
    \tkzTabInit[color,espcl=4,lgt=2.3]
    {$x$ /1 , $f^{''}(x)$ /1 , Convexité\\ de $\left(\mathcal{C}_f\right)$ /2}%
    {$-\infty$ , $a$ , $+\infty$}%
    \tkzTabLine{ , - , z , + , }
    \tkzTabLine{,\text{Concave\hspace{15pt}} ,  , \text{\hspace{15pt}Convexe} , }    
    \node [align=center,font=\small,transform canvas={yshift=-4pt}] at (F2-|N23)
    { point\\ d'inflexion \\$A(a,f(a))$}; 
    \draw (M13) to (N22) to (M23) ;
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]